# Unable to create object from Main

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. This question might be easy, but I didn't find a proper answer to it after my Internet searches.

I have a class with a public method to do some task. From the `main()` method, I'm trying to instantiate an object of my class to further call my method. I'm getting a compile-time error:

> `MyClass`: undeclared identifier

I checked `undeclared identifier` issues to be resolved by wrong spelling or missing namespaces, but didn't find any luck in my case.

I have a single `.cpp` file as below:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass sln; //Error here
    sln.MyMethod();
}
class MyClass {
public:
    void MyMethod() {
        //some code
    }
};
```

Comment: In C++, you need to provide the type before using the type.  Here, MyClass comes after it is used in the code.

Comment: So the class has to be defined before the main method like variables have to be declared before being used?

Comment: @dark_cypher Exactly. However, for a subset of operations, a declaration might be sufficient.

Comment: Well thanks, worked like a charm now. Also, I'm getting this error of insufficient resource error while running my console app and my anti virus is detecting it as a threat. I'm using VS2019 to run my code. How can i resolve it?

Comment: @dark_cypher That depends on what the code you are not showing us does.

Comment: I've a breakpoint on MyMethod call but the issue comes even before hitting the breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the class definition before `main()` here, because it (the compiler) has to know the size of the object it is creating (instantiating).

```cpp
//class definition
class MyClass {
public:
    void MyMethod() {
        //some code
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass sln;
    sln.MyMethod();
}
```

Check out [the working program here](https://onlinegdb.com/S1cv3aZI6).